# Theme Settings value dissapears

Tags: forms

I am trying to create functionality where administrator can upload header image whenever he wants.

I' using `hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter` in theme-settings.php and altering form like this:

```
 $form['theme_settings']['background_file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => t('Background'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://public/backgrounds/',
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('background_file'),
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        ),
    );
```

in `template.php` using hook_preprocess_page and doing this in it:

```
$fid = theme_get_setting('background_file');
$loaded = file_load($fid);
$variables['background_url'] = file_create_url($loaded->uri);
```

and trying to reach `$variables['background_url']` from tpl.php file.

When I upload image everything works great, header image is set properly and code has no problem but after a while, I don't really know what happens, for example after 1 day file_load returns `FALSE`, I just reupload image and everything works fine again.

`theme_get_setting('background_file');` always returns file id without problems.

I am missing something? I can't find source of problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because there is a problem in your template.php. Indeed drupal should save your file only temporarly. You have to save your file permenantly with this code

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['background_file']);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
```